# What's the actual definition of what a Meta "cleanup request" entails, and what's the process for these requests?

Tags: discussion, clean-up

Burnination has clearly-defined rules, processes, procedures, and associated actions - you create a Meta post explaining why the tag meets the [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191). If the Meta post receives enough support, it'll eventually be featured for a few days; if it's still supported after that, it becomes an "official" burnination. Once it's an "official" burnination, the process is fairly straightforward: close and delete the bad questions, retag the rest.

What is the actual process for cleanup, though? What's the actual definition of a cleanup? In what ways does it differ from a "full" burnination (other than the fact that it doesn't result in the complete removal of the tag)? Which actions are permitted as part of a cleanup effort - for example, does a cleanup effort permit retagging?

Also, does a cleanup request ever become an "official" request (like you have for burnination)? The reason I ask is that, with burninations, you're supposed to wait until the burnination is featured and approved before you start retagging. Is there a similar requirement for cleanup? Does it need to be featured and tagged with [status-planned], for example? What actions are you permitted to take, and when? Or can you just go ahead and start cleaning up the tag if it reaches a certain score?

The last question is of particular interest: at what point can you consider a cleanup effort "Meta-sanctioned"?

Comment: A "Tag Cleanup" is just the clean-up part of the burnination process, without the tag removal part. Tag clean-up's don't require consensus because you aren't destroying a tag, you're just focusing your moderation attention to a specific tag. Meta posts for tag clean-up's are a good idea anyway though because they can help muster support and other reviewers. Many hands make light work.